# How to rollback an update on Linux when deploying an enterprise application

Tags: deployment, docker, rollback

What's the best practice to do a rollback to an already deployed  enterprise application on Linux?
Consider this situation, We have an **application server**(let's say it django served by gunicorn), a **data server**(mysql), and a **task server**(celery). And I already deployed them to different servers. Source code is managed by gitlab. When doing update, some error occurred and a rollback is needed.
There are mainly two ways to go:

1. first use `migrate` command in django to rollback status of **data server**; second on **application server** and **task server**, backup the source code before update, and `cp`the backup back when rollback.
2. shutdown all server and make snapshot of server before update. and revert to snapshot when we need rollback.

Of course method 2 is much more safer. But is costly.

Since the situation is developing application for enterprise, I am not very sure Docker is an acceptable solution.

What worries me is the rollback of data server, since the table structure may change, and there are real data in it. And if we use docker, I am not quite sure what to do with the data server, does a image for it is needed?

Comment: Docker is very suitable for Enterprise. I think you should start testing how it works and how to do things the-docker-way. Then you will get a better understanding and see that it is actually a very good solution for you.